# Seaching big files using list in Python - How can improve the speed?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, search, twitter

I have a folder with 300+ .txt files with total size of 15GB+. These files contain tweets. Each line is a different tweet. I have a list of keywords I'd like to search the tweets for. I have created a script that searches each line of every file for every item on my list. If the tweet contains the keyword, then it writes the line into another file. This is my code:

```
# Search each file for every item in keywords
print("Searching the files of " + filename + " for the appropriate keywords...")
for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    f = open(file_path + file, 'r')
    for line in f:
        for key in keywords:
            if re.search(key, line, re.IGNORECASE):
                db.write(line)
```

This is the format each line has:

```
{"created_at":"Wed Feb 03 06:53:42 +0000 2016","id":694775753754316801,"id_str":"694775753754316801","text":"me with Dibyabhumi Multiple College students https:\/\/t.co\/MqmDwbCDAF","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":5981342,"id_str":"5981342","name":"Lava Kafle","screen_name":"lkafle","location":"Kathmandu, Nepal","url":"http:\/\/about.me\/lavakafle","description":"@deerwalkinc 24000+ tweeps bigdata  #Team #Genomics  http:\/\/deerwalk.com #Genetic #Testing #population #health #management #BigData #Analytics #java #hadoop","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":24742,"friends_count":23169,"listed_count":1481,"favourites_count":147252,"statuses_count":171880,"created_at":"Sat May 12 04:49:14 +0000 2007","utc_offset":20700,"time_zone":"Kathmandu","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"EDECE9","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme3\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"088253","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E3E2DE","profile_text_color":"634047","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677805092859420672\/kzoS-GZ__normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677805092859420672\/kzoS-GZ__normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/5981342\/1416802075","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/MqmDwbCDAF","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/Yj1JW9bJ","display_url":"fb.me\/Yj1JW9bJ","indices":[45,68]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1454482422661"}
```

The script works but **it takes a lot of time**. For ~40 keywords it needs more than 2 hours. Obviously my code is not optimized. What can I do to improve the speed?

p.s. I have read some relevant questions regarding searching and speed but I suspect that the problem in my script lies in the fact that I'm using a list for the keywords. I've tried some of the suggested solutions but to no avail.

Comment: are the tweets saved in their original json format?

Comment: @e4c5 I edited the answer to include the information. I'm not sure whether this is the "original json format" because I inherited the files. I haven't used the Twitter API so far. My task is to search.

Comment: Well first off I would compile the regex into one. `pat = re.compile("|".join( keywords),re.IGNORECASE)`, you are also writing the same line multiple times every time you match a keyword which seems wrong. Also if you are only looking to search the text then searching  `json.loads(line)["text"]` might be faster

Comment: now you are talking about a databae, the question title says file. Which on is it?

Comment: @e4c5 Poor choice of words. Like I state on the post, it's a list of files containing tweets in the format I show. Sorry.

Comment: Probably this would speed up drastically using threads & queues. A thread per file, up to a set max.

Comment: If you match 40 keywords in one line do you really want to write the same line 40 times?

Comment: @padraic Very good point. I'll change my code. This is not the issue here but thank you.

Comment: compiling the regex should give you a significant boost, just make sure you compile it once outside the for loops.

Comment: Hi @Aventinus I have a working sample using threads, but have to run, will post late tonight or tomorrow early if still needed.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That would be great Jacob, thank you.

Comment: @Aventinus I just did some tests... while on smaller files, threading/queue -ing gave a substantial improvement, on bigger/many files there is obviously no real improvement. The processor obviously was already 100% used.

Comment: @jacobVlijm I'm still making optimizations. If you want to post your answer and if indeed there is improvement, I'll mark it as correct. The total size of the files is more than 15GBs but each file is ~40MB. I don't know if this counts as "small file".

Comment: I did some extensive testing on the situation you describe. It doesn' give an obvious improvement unfortunately. Would not be worth an upvote :(. The question does though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

### 1) External library

If you're willing to lean on external libraries (and time to execute is more important than the one-off time cost to install), you might be able to gain some speed by loading each file into a simple Pandas DataFrame and performing the keyword search as a vector operation. To get the matching tweets, you would do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe_from_text = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.txt")
matched_tweets_index =  dataframe_from_text.str.match("keyword_a|keyword_b")
dataframe_from_text[matched_tweets_index] # Uses the boolean search above to filter the full dataframe
# You'd then have a mini dataframe of matching tweets in `dataframe_from_text`. 
# You could loop through these to save them out to a file using the `.to_dict(orient="records")` format.
```

Dataframe operations within Pandas can be really quick so might be worth investigating.

### 2) Group your regex

Looks like you're not logging which keyword you matched against. If this is true, you could group your keywords into a single regex query like so:

```
for line in f:
    keywords_combined = "|".join(keywords)
    if re.search(keywords_combined, line, re.IGNORECASE):
        db.write(line)
```

I've not tested this but by reducing the number of loops per line, that could trim some time off.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it's slow**

You are regex searching through a json dump, which is not always a good idea. For example, if you keywords include words like user, time, profile and image each line will result in a match because the json format for tweets has all these terms as dictionary keys.

Besides the raw JSON is huge, each tweet will be more than 1kb in size (this one is 2.1kb) but the only part that's relevent in your sample is:

```
"text":"me with Dibyabhumi Multiple College students https:\/\/t.co\/MqmDwbCDAF",
```

And this is less than 100 bytes, a typical tweet is still less than 140 characters despite recent changes to the API.

**Things to try:**

pre compile the regex as suggested by  [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)

Option 1. Load this data into a postgresql JSONB field. JSONB fields are indexable and can be searched very quickly

Option 2. Load this into any old database, with the context of the text field having it's own column so that this column can be searched easily.

Option 3. last but not least, extract just the `text` field into it's own file. You can have a CSV file where the first column is the screen name and the second is the text of the tweet. Your 15GB will be shrunk to about 1GB

In short what you are doing now is searching the whole farm for the needle when you only need to search the haystack.

Comment: The only problem with this is that I do need the whole line because I'm interested in the metadata that each tweet contains.

Comment: That would apply only to option 3, not for the other two options.